# Bundle in kvmap not showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code:

```
 \begin{kvmap}
        \kvlist{8}{4}{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,0,0}{a, b, c, d, e}
        \foreach \tikzn/\tikzi in {00/0, 10/4, 20/12, 30/8, 40/24, 50/28, 60/20, 70/16,
            01/1, 11/5, 21/13, 31/9, 41/25, 51/29, 61/21, 71/17,
            02/3, 12/7, 22/15, 32/11, 42/27, 52/31, 62/23, 72/19,
            03/2, 13/6, 23/14, 33/10, 43/26, 53/30, 63/22, 73/18
          } {
            \node[font=\scriptsize,color=lightgray, anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (\tikzn.north east) {$\tikzi$};
          }
          \bundle[color=blue, invert=true, vinvert=false, reducespace=-2pt]{7}{1}{0}{1}
        
         \end{kvmap}
```

Gives this:

[image: Properly working K-map]

But when I change the position of the bundle to `{5}{1}{0}{1}` (or anything other than 7 in the first place), the border straight up disappears:

[image: Improperly working K-map - missing border]

I need to have cells 29, 21, 17, and 1 marked: `{5}{1}{0}{1}`. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that the package is not always able to draw the desired bundles. But you can easily draw your own bundle using basic Ti*k*Z commands. I got the following code from the package, so the output should be the same as with your original settings.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,kvmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{kvmap}
    \kvlist{8}{4}{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}{a, b, c, d, e}
    \foreach \tikzn/\tikzi in {%
        00/0, 10/4, 20/12, 30/8, 40/24, 50/28, 60/20, 70/16,
        01/1, 11/5, 21/13, 31/9, 41/25, 51/29, 61/21, 71/17,
        02/3, 12/7, 22/15, 32/11, 42/27, 52/31, 62/23, 72/19,
        03/2, 13/6, 23/14, 33/10, 43/26, 53/30, 63/22, 73/18
      } {
        \node[font=\scriptsize ,color=lightgray, anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (\tikzn.north east) {$\tikzi$};
      }
      \bundle[color=blue, invert=true, reducespace=-2pt]{7}{2}{0}{2};
      \draw[blue, rounded corners=5pt] ([yshift=2pt]01.north west) -- ([yshift=2pt,xshift=2pt]01.north east) -- ([yshift=-2pt,xshift=2pt]01.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]01.south west);
      \draw[blue, rounded corners=5pt] ([yshift=2pt]71.north east) -- ([yshift=2pt,xshift=-2pt]51.north west) -- ([yshift=-2pt,xshift=-2pt]51.south west) -- ([yshift=-2pt]71.south east);
\end{kvmap}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much!